# Overriding a resource route to / (root) in Rails3: not changing the path helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rails-routing

I am quite new to Rails3, I basically created a `subscribers` scaffolding, I only want my app to respond to `new` and `create` actions.

So in `config/routes.rb` I defined:

```
resources :subscribers, :only => [:new, :create]
```

Which works this way

```
GET /subscribers => subscribers#new
POST /subscribers => subscribers#create
```

Now I want my app to exhibit the subscribers resources at `/` (root) instead of `/subscribers`, so here is what I did:

```
match '/' => "subscribers#new"
match '/' => "subscribers#create"
match '/' => "subscribers#thankyou"
resources :subscribers, :only => [:new, :create]
```

Which somehow works, but is probably not the DRYest thing: here are the issues I have:

1. When going back to the form after an issue on a create the browser displays the `/subscribers` URL instead of just `/`, the form is created using the `form_for(@subscriber)` helper method, so the `path` helper must be somehow unaffected by the route
2. Ideally I don't even want the app to respond to a request on `/subscribers`
3. I noticed a weird bug, when posting the form while disconnected (from `/`, and then doing a refresh when the connection comes back (browser ask for resubmitting => OK), the Rails app crashes (I don't have the error stack though as this was on production), why is that?

Also, I tried setting up the route this way:

```
resources :subscribers, :only => [:new, :create] do
  collection do
    post '/' => :create
    get '/' => :new
  end
end
```

Which is probably DRYer, but it doesn't fix any of these issues.

I am sure this is something quite simple, please help!

Comment: You're fighting conventions, and it's always going to be an uphill battle. I would question heavily the reason for not wanting your app to respond to /subscribers and using / for 2 or 3 different actions. You should re-think your architecture.

Comment: Hey bjeanes, I don't want to fight conventions, it's a mailing-list for a "coming soon" soon website, so pretty much the only thing there, I would think there is an easy way to put the resource at /?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Thank you for your answers, it helped me find the exact solution to my question:

```
resources :subscribers, :only => [:new, :create], :path => '', :path_names => {:new => ''}
```

Tested and working on Rails 3 :)

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
resources :subscribers, :path => ''
```

and make sure that `GET /` is being served by your root template, e.g. by adding this to SubscribersController:

```
  def index
    render 'welcome/index'
  end
```

I experimented with using a `match "/"` declaration to override the resource index action and map it to another controller instead but apparently a `resources` declaration is always fully overriding manually declared routes.

Answer (score 0):

For number 2 in your list, delete this line, and rewrite any _path or _url methods in your erb:

```
resources :subscribers, :only => [:new, :create]
```