# In rails is there a way to make a url without the sub folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controllers

I'm wondering if there is a way to make a rails app that works without the controller path.

Typically some paths might be
www.mysite.com/event/slug
www.mysite.com/event/this_is_the_first_event_slug
www.mysite.com/event/another_slug_here

I'm Wondering if there's a way (within the rails paradigm) to create pages off the main path
For example
www.mysite.com/slug
www.mysite.com/this_is_the_first_event_slug
www.mysite.com/another_slug_here

I know it's a small thing, but it bugs me a bit, and I'd like to set it up.

Comment: Actually, a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796979/overriding-a-resource-route-to-root-in-rails3-not-changing-the-path-helper

Comment: This is not the same thing. That is asking how to remove the action aspect of the url. I'm attempting to remove the controller aspect of the url. it's about as different as 1/0 vs 0/1

Comment: **It is the same thing.** `new` and `create` don't have any route suffix by default. That leaves resource prefix (`subscribers`, what you call "controller aspect", possibly because of `SubscribersController`). And accepted answer to that question describes how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define another Route in your `routes.rb` and maybe it's one of the last rules you set, because other routes should match first.

```
get 'event_:slug' => 'events#show'
```

In your `show` method the param `slug` is awailable as `params[:slug]`.

If you want, you can validate the rules with `rake routes` from the command line. After you added your new route to the `routes.rb` file, the command will show something like:

```
GET    /event_:slug(.:format)                 events#show
```

Comment: I think this might be it.. I'll test it tonight when I have the code in hand... thanks.

Comment: @baash05 How is it going?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can.

in `routes.rb`, do like

`match '/event_slug' => 'event#slug'`

that's it. so if you type in browser say www.mysite.com/event_slug then it will definitely work considering routes pattern.

Comment: The match keyword is deprecated since Rails 4. Maybe `slug` is a parameter.

Comment: the problem with that is that event_slug is like the id of the event. They are not set when the app starts, but grow as more events are added.

Comment: so if the `event_slug` is a parameter then routing pattern may get differ.

`get '/:event_slug_parameter', :to => 'event#event_slug'`. i hope this works

Comment: yeah.. it's not really an urgent thing.. Just a bug bear I have with my app. (It may be me procrastinating deploy)